# Receiving an array of MyObject from another app android

Tags: android

I want to design an IntentSerive class in my Android app that receives an array that has objects of MyObject class from another app. The class MyObject is defined in both apps.

I just want to know the steps to make it happen...for example, I know that my service needs to define an intent-filter to communicate with the other app.

Is it even possible? does MyObject class have to be Parcelable?(I don't even know what it is, I read something about it...)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, It's a common task. 
The main purpose of Intents is the communication between independent applications. You are not limited to intents for interaction between your own activity and the service within single application. Android has a special "binding" technique for direct communication between an activity and a background service.

There is an excellent [brief tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can serialize your object to String (by JSON) then pass it as an extra of Intent. Then your app read the String extra and deserialize it.